# One-To-One Self-referencing Problems

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to implement a One-to-One Self-referencing relationship in Doctrine 2. So, my entity Membro_model is:

```
<?php
/**
*
* @Entity
* @Table(name="tb_membro")
*/
class Membro_model
{
    /**
    * @Id @Column(type="integer")
    * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    public $id = 0;

    /**
    * @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL")
    */
    public $nome = 0;


    /**
    * @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL")
    */
    public $email = 0;

    /**
    * @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL")
    */
    public $login = 0;

   /**
    * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Membro_model")
    * @JoinColumn(name="patrocinador_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    **/
    public $patrocinador;

}
```

I can persist entities.  I am having problems in recover data. When the field patrocinador_id is NULL, i have no problem in recover, but when the field is not NULL the following error appears:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 
'application//models/proxies\__CG__Membro_model.php' 
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-
13.1VC9\data\localweb\eliteapp\application\third_party\DoctrineORM-
2.2.2\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 93
```

I am trying to recover using findOneBy:

```
$membro = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Membro_model')->findOneBy(array('login' => $login));
```